# google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api

Google карта на этой странице
http://denispostolenko.com/test/contacts.html
Подсказка, при клике на маркер, появляется над маркером. А нужно под маркером. И чтобы стили подсказки тоже были такими как на картинке.
[image: Карта Google]

Вот код подключения карты

```
function initMap() {

if( document.getElementById("map_1") ) {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_1'), {
                        center: {lat: 56.0080264, lng: 37.4422701},
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        scaleControl: false,
                        zoom: 16
                    });

    var contentString = '<div class="map_tooltip">'+
                            '<h3>ООО «Сервис Принт» <br />Филиал «На Ленина»</h3>'+
                            '<ul class="info">'+
                                '<li><i class="map-mark_2"></i>123123 Российская Федерация,<br /> г. Москва, ул. Ленина, д. 121</li>'+
                            '</ul>'+
                        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-2, 0),
        disableAutoPan: false,
        zIndex: null,
        enableEventPropagation: false
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: 56.0070264, lng: 37.4422701},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: 'Sevice Print'
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

  }
}
```

Как расположить подсказку под маркером и так чтобы стрелочка подсказки показывала снизу вверх на маркер ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расположить подсказку под маркером не получится, а на счёт стилей, ты можешь поместить в это окно любую html разметку с классами и к этим классам задать любые стили